# Como passar uma função em um array no powershell?

Tags: array, windows, script, powershell, automatização

Preciso criar um script, alguns dos campos são evitáveis e gostaria de passar uma função para edita-lo mas quando passo ela dentro do array ela estoura um **ERRO**.

Comment: Tem como compartilhar o código com a gente? O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Sem código sem mensagem de erro não é possível responder nada relevante.